# eventData.points undefined after box or lasso selection

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a scatter plot with a few thousand data points displaying well in Plot.ly.  I'd like the user to use the selection tools to provide more information on the points they've selected, but when I follow the [documentation](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#select-event) to use the plotly_selected event for this the 'points' attribute keeps being undefined.  Here's the example code:

```
$('#myChart').on('plotly_selected', function(eventData) {
    console.log(eventData);

    // this fails because eventData.points is undefined
    //eventData.points.forEach(function(pt) {
    //    console.log(pt.x);
    //});
});
```

And the image below shows me doing the selection, followed by the console output I'm getting.  What am I missing about how to detect the selected points?

[image]

Comment: I think it should be `$('#myChart').get(0).on('plotly_selected', ...` as Plot.ly attaches it's own event handler to the element that was used to initialize the plot, and right now you're working with a jQuery object, not the native element

Comment: Thanks for your response.  When I tried that I got this in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).on is not a function

But your other comments helpfully led me to try tracking it with the element used to initialize the plot instead.  I'll try that route for now.  Thanks again.